# Python - __init__ args

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem.

```
class Operacoes(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.__numero = args

    def get_numero(self) -> int:
        return self.__numero

x = Operacoes(10).get_numero()
print(x)
#(10,)
```

This is making me very intrigued, why does anyone know how to tell me?

args, should return an int in case number 10, but a Tuple is returning.

Comment: 10 is passed as a tuple as you have used `*args`

Comment: I don't see the point of using `*args` here. Just do `def __init__(self, num):` and it'll have the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look closer at the syntax. You assigned

```
*args = 10
```

The star is really important here because it does unpacking of a tuple/list. By Python specification `args` is a tuple, even if it contains a single element.

Then, `self.__numero` stores a tuple. When you retrieve it and print it, it is still a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you call the `get_numero()` method, `self.__numero` is returned. And when looking at `self.__numero` in `__init__()`, it is returning `args`, which is always a Tuple, even if you have only 1 argument.